# " Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list " error and more in Scala

Tags: eclipse, list, scala, compiler-errors

I wrote a recursive parentheses balancing function and there doesnt seem to be any errors in the code but when I run it I get a lot of errors.

I wrote the function with a call like this:

```
if(balance("blarg(arg)".toList)) println("true!") else println("false")
```

and a definition like this:

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean ={

      implicit class MutableInt(var value: Int) 
      {
          def inc() = { value+=1 } 
          def dec() = { value-=1 }                  
      }

        var stack: Int = 0

        def recursbalance(chars: List[Char], stack: Int): Boolean=
        {

            if ((chars.head: Char) == "(".toList) stack.inc()
            else if ((chars.head: Char) == ")".toList) stack.dec()

            if (stack<0) false

            if (chars.isEmpty: Boolean) if (stack == 0) true else false  

            recursbalance(chars.tail: List[Char], stack: Int)

        }
    recursbalance(chars: List[Char], stack: Int)
}
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:337)
at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:334)
at recfun.Main$.recursbalance$1(Main.scala:45)
at recfun.Main$.balance(Main.scala:55)
at recfun.Main$.main(Main.scala:16)
at recfun.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

How do I fix?
sorry for any noobness, I'm new to Scala.

I tried replacing my recursive calls with this:

```
   if (chars.isEmpty: Boolean) {
       if (stack == 0) true else false  
   }
   else
       recursbalance(chars.tail: List[Char], stack: Int)
```

but i still got all the errors..

Comment: you don't check whether the `List` is empty, you need to use a `match` with `Nil` and `x :: tail`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check whether your `List` is empty before you call `head`, `match` is probably the best way to do this:

```
  def balance(chars: List[Char]) = {

    def recursbalance(chars: List[Char], stack: Int): Int = chars match {
      case Nil => stack
      case ')' :: tail => recursbalance(tail, stack - 1)
      case '(' :: tail => recursbalance(tail, stack + 1)
      case x :: tail => recursbalance(tail, stack)
    }
    recursbalance(chars, 0) == 0;
  }
```

I have changed your method a little to remove the `MutableInt` and use an `Int` directly internally.

I ran a quick check:

```
  println(balance("())".toList));
  println(balance("(())".toList));
```

Output

```
false
true
```

Comment: I replaced that part of the code with mine but its underlining the stack.inc() and stack.dec() with red all of the sudden... along with the right bracket of the MutableInt class. and doesnt the function need to be called outside of the definition? this is what gives an error under the MutableInt class I believe.

Comment: If the function had to be called outside of the definition if wouldn't be very recursive... I accidentally put double quotes around the char literals - try with single quotes.

Comment: single quotes didnt change anything.. and I'm not sure but it seems to complain about needing a boolean return value if the call is not put outside the definition.. btw I mean both inside and outside of the definition.

Comment: thanks!! btw what does case x mean? is it an "if anything else" case? and is tail the same as writing chars.tail? and what does the line: "case Nil => stack" mean?

Comment: `Nil` is always the empty `List` - check that first; all empty `List`s are references to `Nil`. `x :: tail` is a catchall, yes; you can also use `_ :: tail` as we don't care about the head in this instance so do not need it assigned to a variable. The matcher breaks the list down into `head` and `tail` so yes, `tail` is just a local variable that refers to the `Lists`s tail.

Answer (score 0):

the particular error in your code is a runtime error. The Scala compiler cannot find out that it will fail at compile time. That's why the code looks okay in the IDE. However, when you run it, the error manifests. It stems from the following lines:

```
def recursbalance(chars: List[Char], stack: Int): Boolean=
{
  if ((chars.head: Char) == "(".toList) stack.inc()

  // ... 

  recursbalance(chars.tail: List[Char], stack: Int)
}
```

You call recursbalance repeatedly with a list which is one element shorter than the previous one. So at some point the list is empty and you try to take the head element from the empty list. That's when you get the java.util.NoSuchElementException.

There are a couple of other things to point out in your code. For example, you're comparing a Char to a List[Char] (list of Chars) in your if conditions. This will always evaluate to false.

Comment: how do I compare it to a simple Char version of the parentheses?

and I thought the line 
"if (chars.isEmpty: Boolean) if (stack == 0) true else false " would stop it from being called when it is empty?

Comment: You don't have an explicit `return` statement therefore Scala returns the value of the last statement in your method - the recursive call.

Comment: @JL as for your "exit condition", you must understand that in scala a method return value is its last evaluated expression, which for your method recursbalance is always a recursive call to itself. The previous expressions involving if checks, doesn't get you out of the call stack for the method. If you need to, you have to write an if-else block where one branch returns boolean, the other calls recursbalance.

Comment: Char literals are written in single quotes, for example '('. if(chars.head == '('). Scala executes the statements from top to bottom. Therefore the isEmpty check is performed after the head element is queried.